# How to customize hover effect region in visionOS

Tags: swift, hover, visionos

In the [Design for spatial user interfaces WWDC video around 13:00](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10076?time=777) Apple states the following in regards to hover effects:

> As you're designing a lock-up, include a shape that will allow the system to display the hover effect as people focus on it. Here, we have some images with text below them. Each lock-up is a single interactive element. You need to define a custom region so it can brighten as people look at it. This helps them understand the entire area is a single element that can be selected. And remember to keep that small space in between each containing shape.

They include examples from Music app:

[image: Music app screenshot 1]
[image: Music app screenshot 2]

I'd like to do this in my app that displays Buttons in a LazyVGrid but haven't been able to achieve that result. I know you need to use the `plain` button style to hide the border button's background yet keep the hover effect. The hover effect appears as an oval though, instead I want it to be a rounded rectangle with additional padding around it and 4pt spacing between the hover effects, as is shown above. How can this be done? I thought `.contentShape(.hoverEffect, .rect(cornerRadius: 50))` would customize the region but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
Button(action: tapAction) {
    VStack {
        Color.clear
            .background(.regularMaterial)
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
            
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Line one")
                
                Text("Line two")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            MarkWateredButton(action: markWateredAction)
        }
    }
    .contentShape(.hoverEffect, .rect(cornerRadius: 50).inset(by: -10)) // FIXME: Doesn't do anything
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

[image: Screenshot from my app]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah like YichenBman says, you do need `.hoverEffect()`. As a bonus. You're background cornerRadius is 10. So the outer radius should be 20 with a padding of 10 to look nice and matching .

```swift
Button(action: tapAction) {
    VStack {
        Color.clear
            .background(.regularMaterial)
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
            
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Line one")
                
                Text("Line two")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            MarkWateredButton(action: markWateredAction)
        }
    }
    .padding(10)
    .contentShape(.hoverEffect, .rect(cornerRadius: 20)) 
    .hoverEffect()
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: Thank you! The combination of padding, contentShape, and hoverEffect in that order achieves this 

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10094/?time=60
This WWDC video is helpful.

You need to add the `.hoverEffect()` modifier to the Stack